UrlFont and kerning
How to set the UrlFont in a way that the kerning is correct?
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}
\def\UrlFont{\itshape}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black,filecolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textit{http://www.dfg.de}\newline
\url{http://www.dfg.de}\newline
\textit{\href{http://www.dfg.de}{http://www.dfg.de}}
\end{document}



You can't,  url uses math mode and there is no kerning. Use \href if you want special formatting

well you could use the last form, but then you give up on line breaking. url uses math mode internally to allow breaks and that affects kerns

xurl allows line breaks between any character but that affects inter-letter kerning, if you use the default url version then only spacing around punctuation characters is affected.
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\def\UrlFont{\itshape}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black,filecolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textit{http://www.dfg.de}\newline
\url{http://www.dfg.de}\newline
\textit{\href{http://www.dfg.de}{http://www.dfg.de}}
\end{document}


